# Как работают срезы с отрицательным шагом?

Tags: python

```
sr =[1,2,3,4,5]
print (sr[::-1])
```

Вернёт [5,4,3,2,1] - это понятно

```
print (sr[0::-1])
```

Вернёт 1

```
print (sr[1::-1])
```

Вернёт [1,2], почему? Откуда начинается отсчёт ?

Comment: Последний пример вернет `[2,1]`, а не `[1,2]`. Вы что-то недосмотрели. Отсчет начинаеем 1-го элемента, шагаем назад на 1.

Comment: @АртемПоликарпов, меня больше смущает, почему отсчёт начинается с 0, а не с 1, как при положительном шаге. При положительном шаге, например, выражение [0::] идентично [::], при отрицательном же нет: [0::-1]!=[::-1]

Comment: @Александр Если вам помог ответ, примите его пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Я просто опишу все варианты:

```
a[start:end] # элементы от start до end-1
a[start:]    # элементы от старт до конца массива
a[:end]      # элементы с начала до end-1
a[:]         # копия всего массива
```

Так же можно добавить значение шага, который может быть использован с любым примером выше:

```
a[start:end:step] # Элементы от start до end с шагом step
```

Другая возможность в том, что start и end могут быть отрицательными, что означает отсчет с конца массива, а не сначала:

```
a[-1]    # последний элемент массива
a[-2:]   # Два последних элемента массива
a[:-2]   # Все за исключением последних двух элементов
```

Точно так же шаг может быть отрицательным:

```
a[::-1]    # Все элементы массива в обратном порядке
a[1::-1]   # Первые 2 элемента в обратном порядке
a[:-3:-1]  # Последние 2 элемента в обратном порядке
a[-3::-1]  # Все за исключением последних 2х элементов в обратном порядке
```

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь не стоит объяснять что список нумеруется с 0, ну вот, первое значение у него 1, потом так как шаг -1 он идёт в обратную сторону, видит что уже конец и прекращает работу. так же и с тем случаем когда ты начинаешь с 1 индекса, сначала он выводит 2, потом 1, а потом прекращает работу. Но, если ничего там не указывать, то пайтон сам подставляет в точку начала значение такие, чтоб он прошел по всем списку. То есть, когда шаг отрицательный, происходит примерно это: `sr[len(sr)-1:0:-1]`, а когда положительный `sr[0;len(rs)-1:1]`.